# Is AES encryption with a custom (non-varying) key secure enough?

Tags: security, encryption, aes

Alright so my question isn't as professional as it can be. Basically I want to know, do you think it's secure enough to encrypt messages with AES and a custom (but static) key?

I want them to be decryptable with that same key but at the same time I don't want anyone who doesn't know the key to get access to them.

I've read that AES is the only government approved encryption method, not sure if its true or not but either way, does not say much.

Comment: AES is the U.S. Government approved algorithm for certains kinds of data. There are other governments and they like other algorithms, e.g. SEED for Korea.

Comment: `I don't want anyone who doesn't know the key to get access to them`. It depends on your key length.

Comment: If you let a real encryption program do the job (like `mcrypt`), then AES is fine as a choice of cipher, but there are other choices that you have to understand and make well (like the mode). If you want to build a solution yourself, I'd hazard that the choice of cipher is probably your least concern.

Comment: how does 16 character sound? long enough to brute force, especially if you add capitals and symbols. If im not mistaken it can be 32 characters too but heard that it might not work on some browsers/operating systems? not too sure

Comment: 16 characters sounds like 128 bits, which is barely adequate if the octets are chosen completely at random and inadequate (as in, does not have 128 bits entropy - randomness) if the 16 characters are running text (passphrases, etc).  But the single key for everyone is a huge problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AES is a secure block cipher algorithm (this is the current opinion of the cryptographic scene), **if it is used correctly**.

This means, that you should use a secure [mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation) - not ECB mode, and a random initialization vector for each message (this can be sent together with the message).

Of course, being a symmetric cipher, this means that you need to have a secret (and authentic, I guess) way to negotiate the key beforehand.

This is not a good idea if you want to embed the key in a software you are deploying to computers you don't control - use a hybrid scheme with a public-key algorithm in this case, as mentioned by Michael.

Comment: May I ask how random IV helps apart from that it will require attacker to make one extra step to understand that first 16 bytes are actually IV? Correct me if I'm wrong, but feels like random IV will not help against real attacker.

Comment: @ruruskyi Sorry if this was maybe worded wrong ... **an IV does not help at all if the attacker knows (or can derive) the key**. But if the attacker does not know the key, the use of a mode of operation with an IV helps against some kinds of attacks (which ones, this depends on the mode, but at least the "same plaintext results in same ciphertext" is always there).

Comment: Assume that we use AES-256 with CBC mode and attacker, of course, does not know the key. Question was why random IV for each message makes algorithm safer?

Comment: @ruruskyi Have a look at the [initialization-vector tag on Cryptography SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/initialization-vector). I'm not going to resume this in a comment here.

Answer (score 2):

The standards that are government approved are all specified by NIST in standard [FIPS 140-2](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcsrc.nist.gov%2Fpublications%2Ffips%2Ffips140-2%2Ffips1402.pdf&rct=j&q=FIPS%20140-2&ei=ZQ5lTs34L9Catwfeu-2MCg&usg=AFQjCNHRNPlOsnW5LWfCGsw0P6yJfvnX_g&sig2=uGygmVd_WJ9DBaydVZ6aIA&cad=rja). Not sure what you will be encrypting to know how secure you need, but one thing to consider would be implementing a hybrid cryptosystem. You could use something like the [Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_Message_Syntax) [[RFC 5625](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652)] or possibly even OpenPGP [[RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880)] format.

Essentially these systems generate a random encryption key to use with AES to encrypt your data. Then you would have a public certificate from the recipient that you would use with an algorithm like RSA to encrypt the random key. Then the two encrypted pieces are combined into a single message.  The recipient then uses their private key and public certificate to decrypt the AES key, then can decrypt the data.

Answer (score 2):

AES is fine.  Use it in CBC mode or CTR mode.  ECB mode is insecure.

A static key is insecure; as soon as an attacker discovers it all past and all future data transfers are no longer secure.  You need to change the key regularly, ideally a new key for each message.

Michael's suggestion to use RSA/Public Key to transfer the changing key is fine, or alternatively use Diffie Hellman to generate a new key with each recipient as it is needed.

You will find that a lot of this stuff is already built into crypto libraries; your general problem is not a new one.

Comment: Suppose you have a server's public key. You generate an AES key, and send it to the server using the server's public key. Do you (opt 1) use the AES key for the rest of the session(assuming a bidirectional connection) or (opt 2) generate a new AES key for each message? Since RSA has bit size limitations and is expensive, wouldn't the 2nd option be even more expensive since you have to do two rounds of encryption and decryption? Which is the best option out of the two?

Comment: That depends on the level of security you require and how long and how many messages comprise a 'session'.  The higher the level of security you need the more you have to pay for it in processing time.  Only you can judge where your particular application sits on the 'secure but costly' to 'cheap but less secure' scale.

Comment: I'm thinking one AES key per session. The messages would need to be instant and so delivery time is important.

Comment: Best to put a limit on how long a "session" can last, say six hours max or 100 messages.  After either is reached then rekey in the background.